# mvc accessing a different model from the strongly typed provided

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, model, viewmodel, model-binding

so I'm writing to see what the best way is to deal with this ish that I have.

I have 3 models and a view that has a strongly typed using one of the models.

Here are the models:

```
public class Car{
  public int CarId
}

public class User{
  public int UserId
}

public class UserCar{
  public int UserId
  public int CarId
     :
     :
}
```

View would be strongly typed with Cars model to provide all the details of the car when the view is visited. But in it I want to have an indicator (maybe a text) that says that the User already has/owns the car which will depend on the UserCar model mapping.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to solve this by passing a strongly typed UserCar Model instead of the cars model and updating the UserCar model to have instances of the User and Car objects for example:

```
public class UserCar{
  public User UserId
  public Car CarId
     :
     :
}
```

this way you can check if userId is null as an indicator.

Just an idea...

Comment: I thought about that. But in my UserCar model, I made the UserId and CarId required fields. So if I would need a Car I would also need a User on that instance but on that page it needs to be able to display the Car instance irregardless if there's a User or not.. does that make sense? so it's
public class UserCar{
[required] UserId
[required] Car Id
}